# ODBC-Performance Access 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access 2010 application. Access is only the Frontend. The Backend is a SQL-Server 2008. The connection between, is ODBC. The ODBC driver is „SQL Server“ (Version 6.01.7601.17514).

I Access is a table with over 500.000 rows. Every row has 58 columns. So the performance is very, very slow, at the most time. To search for one column is not possible, Access is freezing.

I know, that’s not a new Problem...

Now my questions:

Is the driver ok? Because, when I create an ODBC-Connection local (Windows 8), I can choose also the driver „SQL Server“. But here is the version 6.03.9600.17415.

Is there a difference between the speed? I've got a feeling, that, when I use the Acc local under Win8 with the newer driver, it is faster than Terminal Server and older driver.

Local under Win8 I can also choose the driver „SQL Server Native Client 10.0“ (Version 2009.100.1600.01). What ist he difference between those „Win8-ODBC-Drivers“? Which driver would you use and why?

What is with a newer SQL Server? For example 2014 vs 2008. Is 2014 faster than 2008 with ODBC?

What is about the Server-Hardware? When I use a SSD instead oft he HDD? Make a SSD the ODBC-Connection faster?

All users are working on the Terminal Servers. Main with Office 2010, but also with proAlpha (ERP-System). And also with the Access. Now one user told me, that sometimes, if not many users on the TS‘, Access is much faster. What do you mean? When take one TS and work on it, only with Access, not with other application. Is then the ODBC faster?

What can I try else?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There are a lot of things you can try/do but ultimately the only thing that will give you a significant performance boost is move as much of the processing away from the front end and into the back end with the use of Views, Stored Procedures and Functions. There is a world of difference in performance when generating an access report or populating a form by linking to the original tables and having access do all your joins, wheres and groups and doing it all on an SQL Server View and linking directly to that. I have taken processes that took 3 minutes and made them take 15 seconds this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed some performance improvements with SQL Server Native Client 10.0 also using Sql Server 2008 with Access 2010, over the original Native Client.

I would question why you need search/load all 500,000 rows of your table. Assuming this is in a form, it sounds a bit like poor form design. All your forms should only load the records you are interested in, not all records by default. In fact it's considered reasonably good practice to not load any records on form load, until you know what the user is looking for.

58 Columns also sounds a little excessive - are there memo (varchar(Max)) fields included in these columns? These should probably be moved into a separate table. examine your data structure and see if you have normalised it correctly.

Are your fields indexed correctly? If you are searching on them an index will considerably improve performance.

Creating views on sql server that only return a suitable subset of records, that can then be linked as tables within Access can also have performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

A table with 500,000 rows is small – even for Access. Any search you do should give results in WELL UNDER 1 SECOND!

The best way to approach this is to ask a 90 year old lady at a bus stop the following question:

When you use an instant teller machine does it make sense to download EVERY account and THEN ask the user for the account number? Even 90 year old ladies at bus stops will tell you it would be FAR better to ASK for the account number and then download 1 record!

And when you use Google, you don’t download the WHOLE internet and THEN ask the user what to search for. Or do you create one huge massive web page that you then say use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to search that huge browser page.

So think about how near all software works. That software does not download and prepare all the data local and THEN ask you what you want to look for. You do the reverse!

So the simple solution here is to ask the user BEFORE you start pulling data from the server. Build a form that looks like this:

[image]

Then, to match the search (say on LastName), you use this code in
after update of the text box.

```
Dim strSQL     As String

strSQL = "select * from tblCustomers where LastName like '" & Me.txtLastName & "*'"

Me.RecordSource = strSQL
```

That way the form ONLY pulls the data you require – this approach even with 10 million rows will run INSTANT on your computer. The above uses a "*" so only the first few chars of the LastName need be typed in. The result is a form of "choices" You can then jump or edit the one record by clicking on the "glasses" button in above. That simply launches + opens one detail form. the Code is:

```
docmd.OpenForm "frmCustomer",,,"id = " & me!id
```

Let’s address a few more of your questions:

> Is there a difference between the speed? (ODBC drivers)

No, there really no difference in the driver’s performance wise – they all perform about the same and users likely will never see or notice the difference in performance when using different drivers.

> For example 2014 vs 2008. Is 2014 faster than 2008 with ODBC?

Not usually. I mean think of ANY experience you have with computers (unless you are new to computers?). Every time you upgrade to new Word, or new Accounting program, that program is larger, takes longer to load, uses more memory, uses more disk space, and near always uses more processing. So given the last 30 years of desktop computers, in almost EVERY case, the next newer version of software requires more ram, more disk, more processing and thus runs slower than the previous version of that software (I willing to be that is YOUR knowledge and experience – so newer versions tend not to run faster – there are a few “rare” exceptions in computer history, but later versions of any software tends to require more computer resources and not less.

> Now one user told me, that sometimes, if not many users on the TS‘, Access is much faster. What do you mean?

The above has nothing to do with ODBC drivers. In the above context when you are using Terminal Server, the both the database application and the front end (Access) are running on the same computer/server. What this means is that data transfer from the server to the application is BLISTERING fast and occurs not at network speed, but at computer speed (since both database and application are running on the SAME server). You could install Access on each computer, and then have Access pull data OVER the network from the server to the client workstation – this is slow since there is a network. With TS then the application and server run very fast without a network in-between. The massive processing and speed of the application and server can work together – once the data is pulled and the screen rendered, then ONLY the screen data comes down the network wire. The result is thus FAR FASTER than running Access on each workstation.

> that sometimes, if not many users on the TS‘,

Correct, since the users application is running on the server, then no network exists between the application and the SQL server. However since each user has their application running on the server (as opposed to each workstation computer), then more load and resources are required on the server. If many users are using the server, then the server now has a big workload since the server has to run both SQL server and also allocate memory and processing for each copy of Access running on that server.

A traditional setup means that Access runs on each computer. So the memory and CPU to run Access occurs on each workstation – the server does not have to supply Access with CPU and memory, the server ONLY runs SQL server and facilities requests for data from each workstation. However because networks are FAR slower then processing data on one computer, then your bottle neck is not processing, but the VERY limited network speed. Since both Access and SQL and all processing is occurring on the server, then it is far easier to overload the resources and capacity of that server. However the speed of the network is usually the slowest link in computer setups. Since all processing and data crunching occurs server side, only the RESULTING screens and display is sent down the network wire. If the computer software has to process 1 million rows of data, and then display ONE total result, then only 1 total result comes down the network wire that is displayed. If you run Access local on each workstation and process 1 million rows, then 1 million rows of data must come down he network pipe (however, you can modify your Access design to have SQL server to FIRST process the data before it comes down the network pipe to avoid this issue. However with TS since Access is not running on your computer, then you don’t worry about network traffic – but you MUST STILL worry about how much data Access grabs from SQL server – thus the above tips about ONLY loading the data you require into a form. So don’t load huge data sets into the Access form, but simply ask the user BEFORE you start pulling that data from SQL server.